# General strategies for evaluating sums in probabilistic/combinatoric problems: $\sum_n\sum_m {n+m \choose n}p^{n+m}(1-p)^{n+m}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, summation, binomial-theorem

I have encountered the following summation:

$$p^2\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty {n+m \choose n}p^{n+m}(1-p)^{n+m}$$

This summation arises from naive analysis of this simple probability question:

> "Player A plays a match against Player B, and the winner of the match gets a point. Independent matches are repeated until one player is declared the winner by having 2 more points than the other. What is $P(A\text{ wins})$ where $p$ is the likelihood player A wins a match?"

Part of this summation looks very similar to the summation that results from the binomial identity.

---

I missed out on a comprehensive treatment of evaluation of sums and series. I learned a few standard gimmicks like identifying geometric series, Gauss's triangle trick and $\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}=2^n$, but not enough to be completely lost in approaching perturbations of the 'nice' cases like these.

It is somewhat bothering that at this point integrals seem easier to evaluate than summations which are more fundamental and in fact what integration is built off of.

As a general strategy, how does one approach this type of sum?

Comment: The answer, thanks to sage is $$\frac{p^2}{2p^2 - 2p + 1}$$

Comment: Thinking probabilistically, in each pair of rounds, either $A$ wins w/ prob $p_A=p^2$ or $B$ wins with probability $p_B=(1-p)^2$ or the game is repeated. Hence probability of $A$ winning all-together is $\frac{p_A} {p_A+p_B}$.

Comment: think to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method :-)

Comment: Nitpick: the question should say that $p$ is the *probability* that $A$ wins a match, not the *likelihood*.  Likelihood is a different concept in probability theory.

Comment: @Donkey Reverse nitpick: the question is asked (mostly) in *plain English* where likelihood is a *synonym* for probability/chance and your job as a practitioner is not to impose statistical language onto plain English but to be a translator.

Comment: @A.S. I disagree.  The question involves notation from probability theory ($P(A\textrm{ wins})$), so it cannot be taken to be a pure plain English question.  Moreover, this is a mathematics site, and we should expect questions to be asked using the standard mathematical terminology: it was genuinely confusing for me to see the word 'likelihood', before I realized that it should say 'probability'.  Note that my comment is not intended as a put-down or a criticism of the question, but as an attempt to let the OP know that substituting 'likelihood' for 'probability' can be confusing.

Comment: Perhaps I could have rephrased my comment better.  What I meant was 'the term *likelihood* is used separately in probability theory to denote a related, but distinct concept, so it is confusing to use it to mean "probability"'.

Comment: Yes, @Donkey, I was mostly responding to the *should* part of your comment - not (apropos) clarification on the meaning of likelihood vs probability in statistics. More than other areas of mathematics, probability *directly* deals with (and was motivated by) modeling real-life and draws its basic concepts (average, probability, odds, variance, etc) from everyday language/understanding/intuition. I think many mathematicians forget to respect that and as a result I have to explain why probability of $A$ given $A$ is $1$ even when probability of $A$ is 0 ($P(A\mid A)=1$ for all $A\ne\emptyset$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{m \geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}\binom{m + n}{n} p^{m + n} (1-p)^{m+n}
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} \sum_{m \geq 0}\sum_{n \geq 0}\binom{m}{n} p^m (1-p)^m\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=} \sum_{m \geq 0}\sum_{n = 0}^m\binom{m}{n} p^m (1-p)^m \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=} \sum_{m \geq 0} p^m (1-p)^m\sum_{n = 0}^m\binom{m}{n} \\
&= \sum_{m \geq 0} p^m(1-p)^m2^m \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - 2p(1-p)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2p^2 - 2p + 1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Reasons:

$(1)$: Let $q = m + n$, change the index $m$ of the sum to $q$, adjust the sum limits, then rename $q$ as $m$.

$(2)$: $\binom{m}{n} = 0$ if $m, n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $n > m$.

$(3)$: Filter out the part that depends on only $n$.

---

I don't know any general method that applies to all sums of this kind. This is very much trial and error. After some time, you get a feel of what should work.

There are of course many techniques, some originating in Combinatorics (eg. formal power series), that handles specific kinds. If you are interested, I can probably point out some resources.

Also, in my opinion, integration is indeed much easier to handle than sums. Granted it is not fundamental, but because of that very reason, there are many more techniques available. In fact, there is an [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) of infinite series.

Comment: $(m+n,n)\mapsto(m,n)$ is certainly not a bijection on $\mathbb N_0\times\mathbb N_0$.  Perhaps you should rephrase this.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 what do you mean? The inverse is obvious.

Comment: OK then.  What maps to $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Oops! Not my proudest moment. Corrected it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Put $q=p(1-p)$ and use the fact that $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{a+r}a x^r=\frac 1{(1-x)^{a+1}}$$
.

Hence
$$\begin{align}
p^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom {n+m}np^{n+m}(1-p)^{n+m}
&=p^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom {n+m}nq^m\\
&=p^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n\cdot \frac 1{(1-q)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac {p^2}{1-q}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac {q}{1-q}\right)^n\\
&=\frac {p^2}{1-q} \cdot\frac 1{1-\frac q{1-q}}\\
&=\frac {p^2}{1-2q}\\
&=\frac {p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: This follows from $${m+n\choose m}~=~{m+n\choose n}~=~(-1)^n~{-m-1\choose n}~=~(-1)^m~{-n-1\choose m}.$$

Comment: Yes that's correct, thanks. Good illustration using upper negation.